# How to remove unwanted algorithm line numbers?

Tags: algorithms, ieeetran, algorithmic

I am using the IEEEtran template in Overleaf. I am writing an algorithm in the overleaf.
[image]

However, it adds a series of unwanted zeros on the left of the algorithm and also an unwanted `=0` at the last line, here is also my code,

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Migration algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}
    \label{alg:migration}
        \For {$iteration=1,2,\ldots$,N}
            \For {$episodes=1,2,\ldots,M$}
                \State $R_b \leftarrow 0$
                \State $R_l \leftarrow 0$
                \For {$timesteps=1,2,\ldots,T$}
                    \State Run a trajectory $\pi_{\theta_{old/new}}$ for $T$ timesteps
                    \State Compute the timestep latency reward $r_l$
                    \State Compute the timestep binpacking reward $r_b$
                \EndFor
                \State $R_b \leftarrow R_b + r_b$
                \State $R_l \leftarrow R_l + r_l$
            \EndFor
            \State $R \leftarrow w_1 R_b + w_2 R_l$
            \State Optimize the RL Agent policy $\pi$ based on R
            \State Move the containers based on $\pi$
        \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Theses are also the list of packages related to the algorithm that I'm using.

```
\usepackage{algorithmic}[1]
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
```

Instead of zeros I want the line number of the algorithm and also at the end I don't want the `end for=0` part.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: In order to get your code to compile with the `IEEEtran` document class in my TeX distribution (MacTeX2021, all updates applied), I find I mustn't execute `\usepackage{algorithmic}[1]`. Once I make that adjustment, the code doesn't show line numbers. Please confirm that removing `\usepackage{algorithmic}[1]` is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, that solved it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(this answer builds on an earlier comment)

I suggest you (a) *not* load the `algorithmic` package and (b) change `\begin{algorithmic}` to `\begin{algorithmic}[1]` to enable line numbering.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,newtxtext,newtxmath}
%\usepackage{algorithmic}[1] % <-- don't load this package
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Migration algorithm} \label{alg:migration}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1] % <-- added '[1]' to control line numbering
        \For {$\textrm{iteration}=1,2,\ldots,N$}
            \For {$\textrm{episodes}=1,2,\ldots,M$}
                \State $R_b \leftarrow 0$
                \State $R_l \leftarrow 0$
                \For {$\textrm{timesteps}=1,2,\ldots,T$}
                    \State Run a trajectory $\pi_{\theta_{\textrm{old/new}}}$ for $T$ timesteps
                    \State Compute the timestep latency reward $r_l$
                    \State Compute the timestep binpacking reward $r_b$
                \EndFor
                \State $R_b \leftarrow R_b + r_b$
                \State $R_l \leftarrow R_l + r_l$
            \EndFor
            \State $R \leftarrow w_1 R_b + w_2 R_l$
            \State Optimize the RL Agent policy $\pi$ based on $R$
            \State Move the containers based on $\pi$
        \EndFor
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```